# How to escape "<" ">" and everything in between?

Tags: r, string

I have a string variable that contains mixed human language and HTML. I would like to delete all all the HTML portion embed in the "<" and ">". I tried the following:

```
gsub("\\<[^\\<]*\\>", "", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

But I was told that \< is not valid escape. Can anyone help me with the problem? Many thanks!

Comment: "<font size=6>Done with payin good ol Sallie Mae for my learnin at the institushin.</font>" This is how one observation looks like. How can I get it to just "Done with payin good ol Sallie Mae for my learnin at the institushin."?

Comment: What is this comment?

Comment: Edit your question to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` can replace `<tags>` and output content between the `<tags>`.

```
> str
[1] "<font size=6>Done with payin good ol Sallie Mae for my learnin at the institushin.</font>"

> gsub("<.*?>","", str)
[1] "Done with payin good ol Sallie Mae for my learnin at the institushin."
```

Comment: Thanks! I just find how stupid the question was. "<" and ">"s don't need escapes at all.